# Mysql covering index optimization

Tags: mysql

**Table(InnoDB):**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `product_id` int(11),
  `category_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`product_id`)
)
```

I need run the follow SQL queries in my project:

```
1. select `category_id` from `product_category` where `product_id`=?
2. select `product_id` from `product_category` where `category_id`=?
```

I create `PRIMARY KEY(product_id,category_id)` for the SQL query 1

and I create `UNIQUE(category_id,product_id)` KEY for the SQL query 2

I want to know that right?

any others optimization possible?

thanks a lot

Comment: `category_id` might be a usual btree index (`category_id`) without additional unique constraint, the PK columns are implicitly added to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `INNODB` engine, there is no need for second composite index (on `category_id,product_id`). It's enough to have an index just on `category_id` because all secondary indexes keep a copy of primary key

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create the unique constraint for those fields if you already have a primary key for them (if a set of columns is primary key, then the set is also unique).

You can set the fields to be unique separately, but only if you are sure that a category_id has a single product_id and a product_id has a single category_id. From the names I deduce that a category probably has more products and a product may be part of more categories. If this is the case you shouldn't create unique constraints at all.

Optimization: If you don't have so many categories or products you should define these fields to be of smaller size (maybe int(5)).